How to store assets like images in Firebase and use them in my React project?
I want to know how to store some images in Firebase and render them in my React project. Please note that this is not about user-uploaded images. The documentation on Firebase also focuses on how to upload user-generated images.
What's the procedure to simply store the images and use them in my project? Can someone please help me with this?

if you don't want to use the API to upload images, you can upload them to the Firebase console, and then download them in your app through the API.
